# Windows 10 (1909) Crashes instantly and boots into BIOS and doesn't recognize my HDD

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1909

since last week I use my laptop with Windows 10 1909 64-bit, and works fine. But, this week I'm having problems using it. I boot it up, it works, but then after 1-3 hr using it, it crashes. But I can't pick up the error code because it reboots instantly into BIOS and doesn't recognize my HDD. I reboot it up, it works like before but when I play on my laptop, it doesn't crash, today I used it with my friends because we have to do a PowerPoint presentation, and like before, it crashes. Only the first time it BSOD, I used BlueScreen Viewer and the code is KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR.

P.S It crashes in English, but I have only the Italian Language Pack installed, and when i log in it says something like "Windows Security Center isn't active" and it turns out that isn't on Windows. I tried SFC /scannow it's not repaired, tried DISM, again not repaired, I tried again with applying patches, but Windows crashes when doing it.

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If need this:

Intel i3-4005U @1.7 GHz
4GB Ram SDRAM DDR3L 1666MHz
NVIDIA 920M 2GB
HDD 1TB TOSHIBA

EDIT #2: I played CS:GO and it crashed anyway

Comment: All errors you have point to a bad hard drive. Have you checked the SMART attributes using either Speedfan or crystaldiskinfo, or anything else?  https://crystalmark.info/en/download/   http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php  Check the SATA cable too for anything loose.

Comment: What do you mean by “not repaired”?

Comment: @Ramhound throws errors. SFC is like Cannot repair some files. DISM is because for updates it stops on 90% circa Cannot find source files

Comment: @Natsu Kage about the HDD I had a problem with Windows Boot Manager and I found like 2 clusters were damaged. I'm going to use crystaldiskinfo. I'll update you. EDIT: I opened it and it says "Health Status: Caution", how can I check SMART attributes and what is SMART?

Comment: @Davide Caution means exactly this: **your hard disk is failing**. You will need to replace it. Post a screenshot of crystaldiskinfo and I'll confirm

Comment: @Natsu Kage when I come back at the computer I'll send you the screenshot. Thank You! EDIT: Since thay my resolution isn't high I did 2 screenshot because crystaldiskinfo wasn't displaying all of IDs and Attribute Names. 1st https://m.imgur.com/a/a5dad4k 2nd https://m.imgur.com/a/jiRlpnT

Comment: @Davide That hard drive is indeed failed. As DrMoishe said, save whatever you can and replace it.

Comment: @Natsu Kage Ok I'll do it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salvage what you can from the disk, and then replace it.

For short-term use, you could run entirely from a flash USB drive (ignoring  the HDD) with a live Linux distro such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).  Since Ubuntu comes with the LibreOffice suite, you could still do your PowerPoint presentation using LibreOffice's *Impress*. Note, though that flash USB is much slower than a HDD.

Comment: @DrMoische Pippik ok I'll do it. Thank you!